# Trying to display image as black and white pixels only with matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I read a source file which contains coordinates and pixel values (-1 is white and 1 is black) as follows:

x y pixel_value

0 0 -1

0 1 1

0 2 -1

I store the pixels in a numpy array called my_array (size: 100x100), and before I start performing some analysis on the picture I print it using the command:

plt.imshow(my_array, cmap="Greys")

The problem is that the image that is printed is not just black and white pixels, it also shows some gray levels.

I have tried changing the -1s back to 0 sweeping thru the array, but the resulting image still shows gray pixels. I am really baffled by this.

Are these just artificial artifacts, or are they for real ? Why does the zoom in the original png file does not show any gray values no matter how close I get ?

Examination of all the values in the original list and array shows only the integers 1 and -1.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: try this : `cmap=plt.cm.gray`  ... For strictly binary try this `cmap=plt.cm.binary`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I also found out that for the command above 0 is black and 1 is white, which is backwards from the file I'm reading, in which white is supposed to be -1, and black 1.

Comment: hope this solves your problem :D ... Happy to help

Comment: Strange. I don't get any greys, only binary B&W... What version of matplotlib are you using? Anyway, if you want to switch blacks and white you can try simply invert the sign in `plt.imshow(-my_array)`.

Comment: I actually tried that and it worked like a charm. Sometimes the best answers are the simple ones.